# Google Finance Data In WCF service

Tags: c#-4.0

I made C# WCF service which consumes data from **'http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NSE:NIFTY'**.

Here 'NIFTY' can be replaced by other company symbols. It gives me data in JSON format as follow :

```
"// [ { "id": "4899364" ,"t" : "20MICRONS" ,"e" : "NSE" ,"l" : "31.60" ,"l_fix" : "31.60" ,"l_cur" : "Rs.31.60" ,"s": "0" ,"ltt":"3:22PM GMT+5:30" ,"lt" : "Aug 11, 3:22PM GMT+5:30" ,"lt_dts" : "2014-08-11T15:22:34Z" ,"c" : "+0.50" ,"c_fix" : "0.50" ,"cp" : "1.61" ,"cp_fix" : "1.61" ,"ccol" : "chg" ,"pcls_fix" : "31.1" } ] ".
```

I take this output in C# list and returns this C# list to program which consumes this web-service. After getting this list in program, I convert the list into data-table for my further purpose.

But sometimes it gives data as

```
`"<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><script>(function(){(function(){function e(a){this.t={};this.tick=function(a,c,b){var d=void 0!=b?b:(new Date).getTime();this.t[a]=[d,c];if(void 0==b)try{window.console.timeStamp.............".`
```

Can anyone find out this behaviour of Google Finance Output?